# How to label satellite images for Image segmentation?

Tags: tensorflow, label, data-annotations, image-segmentation, satellite-image

I want to detect Land mines in satellite Images. Initially I built a model with each image having multiple labels and trained it to classify the images.

However I want to use Image Segmentation technique as mentioned here : https://towardsdatascience.com/dstl-satellite-imagery-contest-on-kaggle-2f3ef7b8ac40

I downloaded the required images through aws s3 bucket. I want to label each pixel of the multispectral image I have generated from Band files.

However I am facing difficulty in how to labelling.

Are there any open source or otherwise tools to do the same.

**EDIT : The images are 12 band multispectral satellite images.**

Answer (score -1):

You can use AWS Ground Truth to create a job that can label the images you require. AWS also has released which might help https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-sagemaker-ground-truth-adds-auto-segment-feature-for-semantic-segmentation-labeling/

Comment: Since the images are satellite images, is there any way of labelling the pixels using only the numpy array of image?